# How to display output on single line?

Tags: shell

How would get a something like this for example in git when I do cat /.ssh/id_rsa.pub

```
    ssh-rsa 
    AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCvS2bHikv4KsAAPfX6uRovwuZ3YPcx63DnykdBfEejw3/VaDooKVDRYaW6G7rjSub9iug82oD6Kk2n0Txk3CHpNjCDmoKyI1g7HgHjFMFl3q3qsejMhWtHVz176adlaqXRdYZaMnMXON54Khz2V/7Ghg2wMPG+e6NziGxJF3GvrTaiI/TtkehkZH4htkMy1Vr5mE1Vn5BpkacO7Ms8748xaTgfWVt4ssd8cDR5voxClKBVGJEeir5fLVC0HEJv9p6FFkPMV/qpffxGrvdZ4rUxuh/zhVznALsuhc0sSdDueCtcIcOqE2iwijrwi5uw3irdmfdsnkvsdfasd
    Johnny@Johnny-PC
```

Into one line using the cat command that is suppose to print out text in the file in git like so:

```
    ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCvS2bHikv4KsAAPfX6uRovwuZ3YPcx63DnykdBfEejw3/VaDooKVDRYaW6G7rjSub9iug82oD6Kk2n0Txk3CHpNjCDmoKyI1g7HgHjFMFl3q3qsejMhWtHVz176adlaqXRdYZaMnMXON54Khz2V/7Ghg2wMPG+e6NziGxJF3GvrTaiI/TtkehkZH4htkMy1Vr5mE1Vn5BpkacO7Ms8748xaTgfWVt4ssd8cDR5voxClKBVGJEeir5fLVC0HEJv9p6FFkPMV/qpffxGrvdZ4rUxuh/zhVznALsuhc0383290jnfdsafdjasa Johnny@Johnny-PC
```

EDIT: I have tried using cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | awk '{print}' ORS=' ' but it still does the same thing.. I get this:

[image]

I have also tried using cat somefile | tr -d '\n' but unfortunetely it gives me the same results too:

[image]

Comment: What does "using the cat command in git" mean? You may need to edit the question and be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have to replace the new line with empty string

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | awk '{print}' ORS=' '
```

This will print it on a single line

---

### ***`Demo`***

[image]

Comment: This does not work somehow.... I have a picture above showing how I use the same exact command but it still prints it out all on 3 lines

Comment: It should be on 1 line but if it does not fit int the terminal it will be splitted on the screen over 3 lines.

Comment: The actual content is a single line

Comment: Yeah it doesn't fit on the terminal, I was thinking of that, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be the simplest way. Tr just deletes the new line characters.

```
cat somefile | tr -d '\n'
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me for some reason, I posted a picture above of me using that command

Answer (score 0):

remove newlines and spaces from key's

```
cat id_rsa | tr '\n' ' ' | sed 's/ //g'
```